# Error in pnbinom(counts_sub[a, b] - 1, mu = old_mu[a, b], size = 1/old_phi[a])

Tags: r, batch-normalization

I'm trying to perform batch correction on raw RNA-Seq counts. However, when I try to run ComBat, this is what happens:

```
library("sva")
batch <- c(rep(1, 9),rep(2, 19))

adjusted <- ComBat_seq(matr_red_gene %>% select(-GENE), batch=batch, group=FALSE)
```

> Found 2 batches 
>  Using null model in ComBat-seq.
>  Adjusting
> for 0 covariate(s) or covariate level(s)
>  Estimating
> dispersions
>  Fitting the GLM model
>  Shrinkage off - using GLM
> estimates for parameters
>  Adjusting the data
>  Error in
> pnbinom(counts_sub[a, b] - 1, mu = old_mu[a, b], size = 1/old_phi[a])
> :    Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Do you have any advice, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, share the output of `dput(matr_red_gene)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Anyway, I can't view the whole output cause it's too long, but there are the counts separated by commas as follows:  41, 188, 943, 175, 19, 476, 484, 79, 9, 194, 83, 39, 601,  6, 109, 438, 17, 1, 280, 169, 93, 91, 1837, 484, 164, 181, 142, 24, 350, 707, 445, 597, 565, 1, 108, 1, 314, 190, 1, 278, 405, 172, 326, 789, 448, 1232, 0, 490, 1094, 1030, 266, 679, 531, 2, 2798, 17697, 1968)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25046L))